# Levels - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have 10 Levels. Just like a normal game, you can't play the next level unless you beat the level before it. The only parts that change on each level is, one sprite and the sprite's position.

How could I make it so if you beat the level the next level unlocks, then distinguishes which level you are on and loads the defined "details"(meaning sprite file and position)?

Any help is great appreciated! Thanks!

***EDIT:***

I used a plist to load all the information regarding the level

First, I created the PLIST(right click a group then, click resources, "Property List"). Next, I defined all information within the PLIST.

Then, I set up a global variable to set the level number. When the user chooses whichever level(which is a CCMenu), the method changes the int "level" to the correct level number(e.g. 1,2,3,4,5). Then, in my game init it checks the int "levels" and runs the level from the PLIST.

This is in my level methods that the gamescene init runs after the level check. It loads the PLIST, sets the dictionary, chooses the background, adds it to the layer, then the ints "_ballX, _ballY" are declared in the .h file which sets the value for the ball's position located in the init!

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Levels.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistDataAll = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
NSDictionary *levelData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[plistDataAll valueForKey:@"LevelOne"]];

NSString *background = [levelData objectForKey:@"LevelBackground"];

_m = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:background];
_m.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
_m.position = ccp(0, 0);

[self addChild:_m];

_ballX = [[levelData valueForKey:@"BallPositionX"] intValue];
_ballY = [[levelData valueForKey:@"BallPositionY"] intValue];
```

Hope this helps someone! Thank you to everyone for the very quick responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your level class load the data for the level from some data file (a plist file, or xml, or whatever). Then whenever you want to load a different level just point to a different data file.

As for unlocking levels, simply make an array of levels along with their locked/unlocked status that the level select class uses to display the different levels. Between games that information can be stored in another data file (again, a plist file, or xml, or even using CoreData).

Answer (score 3):

The way I handled it is basically have an abstract class, and implement this abstract class in a separate class for each level, then whenever that level is done, simply load the next class (level).

Comment: Basically, you have a separate class for each level with the sprites, etc.? I was hoping I didn't need to do that since I only have 10 levels and I'm only changing 2 things each time. Is there any way to check the level? Maybe, use a global int for the level number then check the int and determine which sprite to add and where to move it?

Comment: Alternatively you could create a .plist file that contains all of that information and just have your scene obtain it's data from the plist

Comment: Well I think it is the cleanest way to do it yes, you just separate what changes and put all the constant stuff in your abstract class or just a super class. It might look like a lot of files, but I think it is easier to mantain this way.

Comment: @Dream Lane, I have no idea how to do that... I'll start looking.                                                               @OscarMk, if I can't find any other way that will be my only option.

Comment: The PLIST is definitely the way I would recommend.  It is very easy.  You just use it as a dictionary...or a dictionary of dictionaries if you like.

Comment: @Dream Lane how do you create a plist?

Comment: A plist file is simply a text file with certain tags in it to organize the data. Personally I would have recommended XML instead because it's a more widespread format but it amounts to the same thing so it doesn't really matter.